# Loop in expect script to send multiple send commands

Tags: expect

i'm out of solutions...
i try to send multiple command after login automatically into a server

```
echo_test2 () {
    /usr/bin/expect  << EOF                                                                                          
    spawn ssh testserver

    foreach rules {6 7 8} {
    send "echo $rules"
    }
    expect eof
EOF
}
```

the result is:

```
test@testserver:~$ echo echo echo
```

when it should be

```
test@testserver:~$ echo 6 echo 7 echo 8
```

Anyone knows how to make it work ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: i found the noob mistake, i was using the script inside a bash script so i had to add a "\" before rules in order to interprete in inside expect

Comment: Another option is to quote the heredoc: `expect << 'EOF'` -- see https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Here-Documents